# Getting LifeCiycleException using Docker Maven Plugin on Ubuntu 14

Tags: maven, ubuntu, docker, jolokia

I am using the jolokia Docker Maven Plugin for building a Java Application on Ubuntu 14  on a VM.
Everytime I try `maven clean package` I get

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.11.0:build (build) on project
>   places_app: Execution build of goal
>   org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.11.0:build failed: No url given and
>   no DOCKER_HOST environment variable set -> [Help 1]

The DOCKER_HOST is set to:DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:4243

When trying `telnet localhost 4243` the connection doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you have a Docker daemon running locally (or within some VM like for Boot2Docker or Vagrant ?). Also, if you start the daemon you should take care that is opening a TCP port for an IP based access (in addition to the Unix socket based one). I.e. it should have been started with a -H option.

The error message itself indicates something different, though. Do you really exported the DOCKER_HOST variable on the server where Maven is running ? What do you see when you echo $DOCKER_HOST ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ubuntu

Open `/etc/default/docker` file and add below line at the end of file

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Then restart the docker deamon

```
sudo service docker restart
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243
sudo netstat -plant | grep 4243
```

#### boot2docker

Open `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` file and add below line at the end of file

```
DOCKER_TLS=no
DOCKER_HOST="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243"
```

Then restart the docker deamon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
sudo netstat -plant | 4243
```

Add the below in your environmental variable in windows / mac

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:4243
```

Now do

`mvn docker:build -Ddocker.skip=false`

it should work

Note: Create the file If its not there in the particular location.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using the "put a file in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d" config style instead of "edit /etc/default/docker" config style, setting this as the contents of my /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/socket.conf file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

and running these commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

and of course setting the DOCKER_HOST as described above, did the trick.